# Set a default search engine for the whole company via Active Directory with the option of switching (back) to a different one

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2016, search-engine

Disclaimer: I am new in the field and my knowledge about AD is extremely small yet.

So I was sent a package with Group Policy templates to implement in an Active Directory, so the default search engine of Internet Explorer and Chrome will be Ecosia. The only problem is, that management wants to give the users the option, to switch it back to an other search engine of their liking, if they are not happy wit Ecosia, and this is not possible yet. It is a hard switch right now.

So, how can I implement the option of the users to switch to a different search engine?

Comment: Pain in the ass, but why not 2 sub- OU's one for default and one for opt-out. You could set up a group policy that only contains the Ecosia settings and apply it to the default OU, then if someone wants to move, just drop them in the opt-out OU. Obviously depends how you've set up your AD and where the majority of your users are sitting, and it's a pain in the ass to administrate, but it is an option. (Or limit the scope to those [not] in an AD group and just add remove from the group)

Comment: That does sound like a pain in the ass. So every employee would have to shoot the admin an email with the wish of opting out?

Comment: Yeah... or setup an internal website (self service) that has permission to change them between AD groups somehow via script or something.